# css data:image won't show in Firefox 58

Tags: css, firefox

I have trouble showing the data:image svg.

On my website I use this css snippet:

```
        #menu > .close:before, #menu > .close:after {
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 2em 2em;
        }

#header nav ul li a[href="#menu"]:before {
                        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 8px%3B stroke: %23f2849e%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='25' x2='100' y2='25' /%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='50' x2='100' y2='50' /%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='75' x2='100' y2='75' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
                        opacity: 0;
                    }

#header nav ul li a[href="#menu"]:after {
                        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 8px%3B stroke: %23585858%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='25' x2='100' y2='25' /%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='50' x2='100' y2='50' /%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='75' x2='100' y2='75' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
```

It shows correctly in Chrome and used to show correctly in Firefox 57. But with the new update to Firefox 58 no svg file is shown anymore. So I looked into it and while inspecting the layout files in Firefox I saw that the above lines get Base64 encoded to e.g.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+PHN0eWxlPmxpbmV7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjhweDtzdHJva2U6IzU4NTg1OH08L3N0eWxlPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDI1SDFlMnoiIC8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTAgNTBIMWUyeiIgLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMCA3NUgxZTJ6IiAvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
```

Which won't display a svg file. I have no clue how to solve this problem. Maybe someone has an idea. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, your SVGs render just fine in my copy of Firefox/58.0.1 Win64 ([demo](http://jsbin.com/haloxifuse/edit?css,output)). Are you positively sure that the error isn't somewhere else? The DOM inspector does not reflect the actual source code, it's just a pretty-print representation of the in-memory objects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `base64` data is incorrect. The below code worked for me ([Pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/NyRPzv))

Also you are missing the `content` property. Please take care of it, as its a mandatory property for the `:before` and `:after` pesudo elements.

```
.b:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I only pasted a snippet. I have updated my originial post adding some more lines (e.g. content). However, If I play with the sandbox (Pen) you provided, I do not get an output for my Bse64 encoded String.

Comment: I just converted your `base64` to image with this [website](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and its a white image.

Please compare the below code(yours) and with mine, given in codepen by converting.


`data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+PHN0eWxlPmxpbmV7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjhweDtzdHJva2U6IzU4NTg1OH08L3N0eWxlPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDI1SDFlMnoiIC8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTAgNTBIMWUyeiIgLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMCA3NUgxZTJ6IiAvPjwvc3ZnPg==`

Comment: I'm totally unsure on your statement that Firefox encodes your `base64` to a blank image.
I've tested it in Firefox versions 57 and 58 across Windows 10, 8.1, MAC Mavericks and High Sierra.
It works fine in all the cases.
Here are the links

https://ibb.co/dewW6H, https://ibb.co/i2Ff0c, https://ibb.co/bDg3Lc, https://ibb.co/fLNA0c, https://ibb.co/gLFkYx, https://ibb.co/cbJiLc, https://ibb.co/cvtTmH